# Ansible PlayBook to run a SQL script file

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to create an yaml script to execute the SQL script file Test.sql through playbook

Below yaml script ended with error, please suggest the exact syntax

```
## Groups:
[Database]
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx

##Sample.yaml

- name: "SQL Script Execution"
hosts: Database
tasks:
- win_command: sqlcmd -S {{ Database }} -i "D:\\abc\\sdfbv\\Test.sql"
  register: sqlcmd_out
```

Comment: Could you please share the error.

Comment: Hi Vaishnav, This is my first try, I am not sure about the syntax first , i just verified in yaml validator it throws error like "(<unknown>): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 1 column 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the valid YAML syntax for your Sample.yaml,

```
- name: "SQL Script Execution"
  hosts: Database
  tasks:
    - win_command: sqlcmd -S {{ Database }} -i "D:\\abc\\sdfbv\\Test.sql"
      register: sqlcmd_out
```